# ActiveRecord, Squeel: Getting objects without parent associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, squeel

I have:

```
class ThingsCollection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :things, uniq: true
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :things_collections, uniq: true
end
```

I want to get `Thing`s which don't have any `ThingsCollection`s (`thing.things_colllection_ids.empty? == true`). How can I do this via ActiveRecord & Squeel? (Without SQL query if possible)